# Android - Read an XML file with HTTP GET

Tags: android, xml, get

I need to explore for my project use of web services on Android. I know that there is no official library for XML - RPC web service.

But there is for REST XML and i need to test it.

I would like to read XML on my web page (Where i have to pass username and Password) from Android with HTTP GET.

**OR**

Suppose, i follow  [**This link**](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/), then where do i pass username and password?

Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: How are the username and password required? If it's HTTP Basic Auth then the HttpClient library supports that and you can add to Gianni's code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
HttpGet uri = new HttpGet("http://example.com");    

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(uri);

StatusLine status = resp.getStatusLine();
if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
    Log.d(tag, "HTTP error, invalid server status code: " + resp.getStatusLine());  
}

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(resp.getEntity().getContent());
```

Comment: Don't forget to close up your HTTP request! resp.getEntity().consumeContent() - only need to do this in the event that the XML parsing doesn't fully read the file though, so in a finally block in some form.

Comment: @Nick Yeah!  Actually, that is only a snippet of a much bigger code I have running.  I just took the relevant parts to get started.

Comment: Cool beans - it's just a common error in HTTP requesting so I thought I'd mention it for everyone's benefit. Personally I like using the execute() methods that take a ResponseHandler, since they guarantee everything is released after the handler is called.

Comment: just add this line to pass "Username" and "Password" :
  httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
               new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Please tell me the `Uri` value?

Comment: Should be? => if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {

Comment: For future reference: that `uri` object can be constructed as follows: `new HttpGet("http://example.com")`

Comment: @Pieter Updated example.  Thanks!

Comment: [`StatusLine.getStatusCode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode%28%29) returns int, shouldn't be compared to `String`.

Comment: Android says: Deprecated =( @Gianni

Answer (score 2):

This link helped me to get started understanding how to HTTP GET XML and Parse using the SAX Parser.

http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

Hope this helps,

iTom

Comment: @iTom...I already read this article....but then how do i pass "Username" and "Password" value.....btw thanx

Comment: With a GET request the form values are usually appended to the URI request instead of posted
i.e.
http://www.example.com/webservice.php?username=iTom&password=MyPassword

Hope that helps, iTom

Comment: Oh also if your after a function that builds the URI for a GET request then this article may also help..
http://www.anddev.org/doing_http_post_with_android-t492.html

Comment: Hey Paresh please explain what's happening are you getting an error message? or is nothing being returned?

Answer (score 1):

A few lines of code for HTTP Basic Auth, if you mean this.

```
String auth = Base64Converter.encode(String.format("%s:%s", user, pass));
URL u = new URL(url);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
```

Where "Base64Converter" is a utility class converts a string to its Base64 compiled form.
Do this before the openConnection() call in parsingxml.java, line 36.

Comment: i think this helps me...let me try...give u reply if running..thanx for the support

Comment: Base64Converter is not supported in Android..showing Red line under(error) the Base64Converter

Comment: @Paresh yes Base64Converter is a public domain utility class that I found somewhere else. A Google search might get you the right place. Android meant to have provided an Base64 encoder / decoder class but is actually unavailable to app developers.