# Android: How to set encoding in JSONStringer for webservice requests?

Tags: android, .net, json, web-services, encoding

I finished the English version of my application and I am currently working on my Arabic application version. Although my English webservices were working fine, there seems to be a problem with my Arabic webservices, I feel that I need to specify the encoding type (utf-8) when I construct my JSON request using the JSONStringer class. Is there a way to do that?

Here is an example of a method that constructs my JSON request,

```
public static String initLoginJSONRequest(String username, String password){

String parentString = null;
String childString = null;

try{

    childString = new JSONStringer()
    .object()
        .key("username").value(username)
        .key("password").value(password)
    .endObject()
    .toString();

    parentString = new JSONStringer()
    .object()
        .key("UserCredentials").value(childString)
    .endObject()
    .toString();

}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


return parentString;
```

}

**EDIT**

I would also like to add that I specify that my encoding is utf-8 in my HttpPost as shown below,

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(getUrl);
             StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonString);
             se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");//text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

             post.setEntity(se);
             response = client.execute(post);
```

But it is not recieving my Arabic charecters on the webservice end (written in .NET) correctly.

Comment: Have a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/583562/593709)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change UTF-8 by ISO-8859-1

The answers here can help you:
[Android - Read an XML file with HTTP GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395154/android-read-an-xml-file-with-http-get)