# How to send Xml from rest webservice in visual studio to android with utf - 8?

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I have rest webservice that it's programmed in Visual Studio Asp.net project.
i want to send Array of String that contain Hebrew language to Android project

In visual studio i only write `return array;`

In Android i write:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity7, HTTP.UTF_8);  
return xml;
```

but the problem is that in the Android project i get "??????" instead of Hebrew words
i guess the problem is in the encoding.

Thanks

Comment: [Read an XML file with HTTP GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395154/android-read-an-xml-file-with-http-get)

Answer (score 0):

You are toStringing the entity in UTF_8 format, which is all well and good, but you need to set the encoding of your HTTP response.  You can either do so directly here in code:

```
HttpResponse.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding;
```

Or you can do it globally:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```